# The images of the button is not showing

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the button onclick and also i want to make the button as an image. Here are my code.

```
<input class="refresh" type="button" onClick="clickclick();">
```

and the css code is..

```
 .refresh {
        background: transparent url(click.png) no-repeat;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

The good thing is the button can be click but the image is not showing. Any ideas? I'm trying to put CSS to make it easier but if there is another choice and if it is success, I can give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Where is the Javascript code for your `clickclick()` function?

Comment: @Lodder Irrelevant ;)

Comment: is the path to the image correct? As it stands now, it should be in the same directory as your css file

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Ahh my bad. Too tired to read questions tonight. Sleepy time me thinks

Comment: @Eeji Hey, yes its path to the image correctly. Just it won't showing up. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no-repeat` is a `background-repeat` value. `background-image` expects *only* an image identifier, thus you have bad syntax and it is discarded.

Additionally, you override it anyway with `background:transparent`.

Try:

```
background: transparent url(click.png) no-repeat;
```

OR:

```
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url(click.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol have a look at the question, i've edited there :) should I create JSFiddle? But I can't make the image appear on JSFiddle.

Comment: @Marcel hey that's working. I guess my image is broken. How could that be. Make me frustrated just now.

Comment: @Anthosiast open the image in your browser, copy the URL and paste it in your CSS, can't go wrong

Comment: @Marcel Yes I did. My image is png. Should be that problem? When I right clicked the button and click view background image, the image is still there. How come the image is not showing on the page?

Comment: yes yes you can, [here](http://postimg.org/image/r14rzfwlt/082182eb/). Something like this. :/ @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: I doubt that [this](http://s16.postimg.org/r14rzfwlt/Screen_Shot_2014_05_12_at_23_39_56.png) is the image you are using for your button... We need to see the `click.png` image.

Comment: I get this from [google](http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/brown/recurring-appointment-xxl.png). Anyway I just found out that i put in css is about `30px x30px`. It won't work. And I try to make it big like `300px x 300px`. It works. Is there any way to resize the width and height of the image? @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: Yes. `background-size: 30px;`.

Comment: @Anthosiast `background-size: 30px 30px;`

Comment: However, having an image the right size in the first place would be a good idea. Saves bandwidth, more browser-compatible...

Comment: and maybe one twice as big for retina! Anyway, here is it in all it completeness; http://jsfiddle.net/ZLFG5/1/

Comment: Ahhh yeahh, it works now. I didnt think about `background-size`. Thanks for the advice by the way @NiettheDarkAbsol. And also, why the background looks like transparent? Can we make it look like no background at all, just image?

Comment: to make you guys understand, have a look at [here](http://postimg.org/image/sjw7w0duf/34ed1eaf/).

Comment: Looks like a `box-shadow` being applied by your browser. Try adding `box-shadow:none`.

Comment: and it's done! @NiettheDarkAbsol haha. Thank you very much! Works magic!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `background:transparent;`

Change it to `background-color:transparent;` and your image will appear just fine.

EDIT - @niet's answer is more complete, use his.

Comment: I originally missed the `background:transparent`, but it seems like you missed the problem that I did spot :D

Comment: Nono, I didn't say get rid of it, I said that it doesn't belong there and should be its own property.

Comment: Haha! Yep, that's exactly what happened. Editing my answer now to fix the 'get rid of' statement